# can i use workflow while updating fields

Tags: workflow

If i create a **contact** and add an **account** and update a phone field and saved it then phone must be updated in **account** also. Can i use workflow for it

Comment: Did you already try ?

Answer (score 2):

No, if the relationship is master detail then only parent object record can be updated through workflow. Here Account & Contact has look-up relationship by standard hence it is not possible to update through workflow.

Need to write trigger to achieve the same.

Comment: please suggest me  something how to overcome this problem. can i do this using coding pls suggest me something

Comment: @user4986, as per Samuel, did you try anything or not?

Comment: @user4986 trigger in contact is the possible way.. try this approach menthioned in this like - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21738345/trigger-to-update-account-filed-when-a-corresponding-contact-field-is-updated-i